# Using Classifier with NearestNeighbors methods

Tags: numerical-value, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am using a Machine learning toolbox on mathematica. I have 8 classes.
Training data: for each class, there 100 samples with size 160.
I used this code.

```
trainingset={"class1"->class1train, "class2"->class2train,.....,"class8"->class8train}.
(*note that Dimensions@class**i**train={100,160}. *).
(*for classify, i used the 3rd signature in the documentation*)
classifier = Classify[trainingset, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"];
```

But, I get this error: Only variable can be predicted. What is this problem?

here is a simple example:

```
trainingset = {"A" -> {{1, 1}, {1, 2.1}}, "B" -> {{2, 2}, {2.2, 2.5}},
    "C" -> {{3.5, 2}, {3.2, 2}}, "D" -> {{4, 4}, {4.9, 5}}};
c = Classify[trainingset, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]
```

I have the same error.

Comment: Or, `Classify[Association@trainingset]`. The third form uses `Association` with the classes as the keys.

Comment: @AntonAntonov, it does not work, you can try it on the example in my question

Comment: @rcollyer, thanks, it works.

Comment: I deleted my original comment because the code was wrong.